# No tengo acceso al SQL server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola a todos necesito crear y visualizar los jobs creados en sql server management pero no tengo acceso al sql server agent.

Esto es lo que muestra mi explorador de objetos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es mi version de SQL server managemet studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben como podria lograr utilizar el agent?

gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo necesitas ver cuales son los jobs creados, puedes consultar la base de datos msdb. Ahí se guarda toda la información que usa SQL Server Agent. Para empezar, puedes usar sysjobs.

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

Si quieres ir más a detalle, puedes ver los pasos de cada uno.

```
SELECT j.name,
        j.enabled,
        st.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps st ON j.job_id = st.job_id;
```

Para los horarios puedes usar sysjobschedules y sysschedules, y así con cada detalle.

Comment: Creo que igual necesitaría los permisos necesarios para hacer esas consultas que son los que no tiene ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Dos opciones:

**Opción 1**
Arrancar el Management Studio como Administrador de Windows.

[image: res1]

**Opción 2**
El login con el que inicias sesión tenga privilegios suficientes.

[image: res2]

[Configure Sql Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/agent/configure-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16)